# How do I bring a newly created Outlook email object to the foreground VBA

Tags: vba, api, ms-access

When I create a new Outlook email object it does not always come to the front. 
None of them work consistently. They all stop the taskbar from flashing (which indicates that something has happened) but they never consistently bring it to the foreground.

I have tried:

```
.Display
Visible = True
Application.ActiveWindow etc
```

API calls such as `Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long with SW_SHOW,, SW_SHOWNORMAL,, SW_MAXIMIZE`

This is for Access 2016

```
Call AttachThreadInput(CurrentForegroundThreadID, NewForegroundThreadID, True)
lngRetVal = SetForegroundWindow(MyAppHWnd)
Call AttachThreadInput(CurrentForegroundThreadID, NewForegroundThreadID, False)

If lngRetVal <> 0 Then

    '''Now that the window is active, let's restore it from the taskbar
    If IsIconic(MyAppHWnd) Then
        MsgBox (1)
    Else
        Call ShowWindow(MyAppHWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        MsgBox (2)
    End If
```

It always runs the `Else` part of the code, i.e. Message Box 2. I don't receive any error messages from other parts of the code either.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. After days and days on this. I commented out

```
Call AttachThreadInput(CurrentForegroundThreadID, NewForegroundThreadID, False)
```

I wondered why that bit of code was there. It didn't make sense. Ohhhhh WOW huge. Oh and in the section where the call is made I used

```
Call ShowWindow(MyAppHWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

I also had to change how it is received from the initial call from the module and present the result in a message box. It looks like so:

```
'Call FnSetForegroundWindow(strWindowTitleMine) 'This way does not work
Result = FnSetForegroundWindow(strWindowTitleMine) 'This line is absolutely necessary

If Result = True Then
    MsgBox ("Success") 'This line is absolutely necessary
Else
    MsgBox ("Not successful")  'This line is absolutely necessary
End If
```

Full credit to the person that wrote all the code that does the work. You can view it here [EverythingAccess - Bring an external application window to the foreground](https://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Bring-an-external-application-window-to-the-foreground)